# Release a message back to AWS SQS with 20secs visibility time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I am using **spring-boot:2.2.6.RELEASE** and **aws-java-sdk-sqs:1.11.415**. I have a listener which polls message from SQS. There is a condition where the listener process the message and if the condition is not met then we should place the message back to the queue and it should be available to any other component or same listener after 20secs. I am not sure how to achieve the later one, place message back to the queue and it should be visible after 20secs to other listeners,

Please find below code for reference,

```
@Autowired
private QueueMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

@PostMapping("/employee")
public String save(@RequestBody Employee employee){
    Map<String,Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put("subject", "send employee details to sqs");
    headers.put("name","Donald");
    headers.put("traceId","sample");
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("sample-standard-queue", employee, headers);
    return "success";
}

@SqsListener(value = "sample-standard-queue")
public void receivesqs(Employee message, @Headers Map<String,Object> headers, @Header("name") String name) {

    // Retrieve employee details from DB using message.id
    // If it is in-progress then place the message back to the queue and it should be visible after 20secs
}
```

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404007/release-a-message-back-to-sqs) But it place the message back to the queue and it will be immediately available to other readers. In my case it should be available after 20secs.

Comment: Generally, it is  not a good idea to put a message back onto a queue. If a worker fails to process a message, it will be automatically placed back on the queue after the Invisibility Period expires.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I know if a worker fails to process a message then it will be automatically placed back on the queue. but when it will be available to other readers? My use case is it should available to same or other readers only after 20mins

Comment: When a message is retrieved from the queue, it will remain invisible for the duration specified in the **Invisibility Period**. The queue has a default invisibility period, but it can also be specified when the message is retrieved. The process that retrieved the message can  also `change_message_visibility()` to increase the timeout. If the message is not deleted within the invisibility period, it will reappear on the queue. Therefore, set your invisibility period to a maximum of 20 minutes.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein The default invisibility is 30secs. So If I change that to 20secs then it will be visible again to other consumers in 20secs I believe. The other consumer or reader should finish the processing of the message in 20secs since we change it to 20secs otherwise the message will get duplicated. Am I right?

Comment: Yes-ish. The message won't be duplicated. It will simply reappear on the queue for another worker to consume.

Comment: Ok....may I know how can I change_message_visibility inside consumer?

Comment: [`changeMessageVisibility()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/AmazonSQSClient.html#changeMessageVisibility-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.Integer-)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes I know this method but I doesn't know how to call that method inside the consumer. Do we have any code sample?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein There is an interface visibility ..we use visibility to change the visibility timeout of message

Comment: Ah! You are using Spring and it doesn't seem to use the normal interface to SQS. I'm not a Spring person, so I don't know how you would interact with SQS API calls from Spring.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned here [SQS Listener Manual Acknowledgement](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/134)

`@SqsListener(value = "sample-standard-queue", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.NEVER)` would not delete the messages, you can manually delete them by having a acknowledgment parameter.

```
 @SqsListener(value = "sample-standard-queue", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.NEVER)
    public void receivesqs(Employee message, @Headers Map<String,Object> headers, @Header("name") String name,Acknowledgment acknowledgment)  {
        // decide when to acknowledge
        acknowledgment.acknowledge().get();
    }
```

Based on your visibility timeout settings, message will reappear in the queue after the visibility timeout seconds.

Comment: How to delete the message based on acknowledgement parameter?

Comment: @VelNaga if you dont acknowledge then its by default unacknowledged.